# Google App Script cannot fetch CSS file hosted on Google Drive (403 unauthorized)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a problem with Google App Script accessing Google Drive hosted assets. And the strange fact is that it was working all the time and just stopped working several days ago.

What is happening: In google app script html we have a link to CSS file (and other assets) hosted on google drive. The link is provided in following form:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://drive.google.com/a/<<my.company.com>>/uc?id=1K33XlNMHDH8VSoPFciJJi-6jy0vofDqQE">`

When page is loaded there is 403 Unauthorized error during fetch call for that resource. The resource is visible for currently authenticated account running web app.

When I access it directly from web browser (url address bar) - the resource is downloable.

All resources google app script tries to fetch are publically visible within my company domain for people who has an access link.

Comment: Maybe related: https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/blog/cookie-countdown-2024jan